# ToolbarItem text color in NavigationPage on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

In my app I have `NavigationPage` with title and `ToolbarItem`. I'm using styles in `App.xaml`:

```
  <Style x:Key="TopBar" TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource TopBarColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Black"/>
  </Style>
```

On Android top bar looks like

[image]

where title is  black and `ToolbarItem` text is blue. This is exactly what I want.
But on iOS bar looks like

[image]

So my question is how to make `ToolbarItem` text color blue and leave title's color black.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most general and certainly effective methods is to use `Navigation.Titleview` instead of `ToolbarItems`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TitleViewSample"
         x:Class="YourPage">

  <NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Welcome" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Label>

        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,5,5">
            <Label Text="LOGIN" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Blue" Margin="10" ></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
  </NavigationPage.TitleView>


</ContentPage>
```